# Getting the Error Despite Correct Output

Tags: python-3.x

getting this error meassage despite having exactly same output as expected output.

*** ERROR: Expected to find a number in the line Available Letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.
 Check to be sure your lines match up with the expected output!!! ***

MY CODE:

```
def hangman(secretWord):
    print ("Welcome to the game, Hangman!")
    print ("I am thinking of a word that is " + str(len(secretWord)) + " letters long" )

    lettersGuessed=[]
    guesses = 8
    p = " "
    while guesses > 0:

        print ("You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses left")

        print ("Available Letters: " + str(getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed))),

        user_input = input("Please guess a letter: ")
        user_input = str(user_input)
        user_input = user_input.lower()

        if user_input  in lettersGuessed:
            print ("Oops! You've already guessed that letter: " + str(getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed)))
        else:
            lettersGuessed.append(user_input)
            if user_input in secretWord:
                print ("Good guess: " + str(getGuessedWord(secretWord,lettersGuessed)))
                if isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
                    break
                else: continue
            else:
                print("Oops! That letter is not in my word: " + str(getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed)))
                guesses = guesses - 1
    p = str(getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
    p = p.split(" ")
    p = "".join(p)
    p = str(p)

    if p == secretWord:
        print ("Congratulations, you won!")
        return
    else:
        print ("Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was " + secretWord + ".")
        return
```

[image: output screenshot]

Comment: Looks like the output *must* match *exactly* and you're possibly missing the `-----------`, etc. So check each line and `"be sure your lines match up with the expected output"`

Answer (score 0):

Check each line and "`be sure your lines match up with the expected output`". 
It's possible  the automated system that is checking the output requires the lines of output must *exactly match* their "`correct output`" **including** the `-----------` lines, and you're code doesn't print those lines.

Easy as:

```
print ("I am thinking of a word that is " + str(len(secretWord)) + " letters long" )
print ("-----------")   ### <---- Add this one line
lettersGuessed=[]
```

and

```
print ("Good guess: " + str(getGuessedWord(secretWord,lettersGuessed)))
print ("-----------")   ### <---- Add this one line
if isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
```

It's possible that you'll need to add that one line in other conditions within the code, as in the `else:` conditions.

And as always to make debugging easier, less repetition and cleaner code, you could assign that output to a variable and print it when needed:

```
def hangman(secretWord):
    line_break = "-----------"
    ...
    print ("I am thinking of a word that is " + str(len(secretWord)) + " letters long" )
    print (line_break)
```

, etc.

Hope this helps.